# Probability of $U<V$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have following exercise:

Let U, V, W be independent with uniform distribution on (0,1). We have indicators:

$$
I_1 =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  1  & U<V \\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
 \end{array}
\right.
$$

$$
I_2 =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  1  & V<W \\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
 \end{array}
\right.
$$

Calculate $var(I_1+I_2)$!

So far, I got those results:
 $$var(I_1+I_2) = var(I_1)+var(I_2)+2cov(I_1,I_2)$$
$$var(I_1) = E(I_1^2)-E(I_1)^2=P(U<V)P(U\geq V)$$
$$var(I_2) = E(I_2^2)-E(I_2)^2=P(V<W)P(V\geq W)$$
$$cov(I_1,I_2) = E(I_1 I_2)-E(I_1)E(I_2)=P(U<V, V<W)-P(U<V)P(V<W).$$

Now, I have problem calculating $P(U<V)$.

Can I say $P(U<V, V<W) = P(U<W)$ and $P(U<V) = P(V<W) = P(U<W)=p$. Then $var(I_1+I_2)=4p(1-p)$. But I still need to calculate $p$. How do I do that? Thank you.

Comment: HINT : $ 1 = \mathbb P( U < V) + \mathbb P(V < U) + \mathbb P(V=U)$. Now, why $\mathbb P(V=U) = 0$? and why $\mathbb P(U <V) = \mathbb P(V<U)$ ? Having that, can you finish? Also u can't say $\mathbb P(U<V<W) = \mathbb P(U<W)$, because the role of $V$ is important, however u can proceed similar as above. Try to generalize the reasoning to get $\mathbb P(U<V<W) = \frac{1}{3!}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that $U<V, V<W \implies U<W,$
but $U<W \kern.6em\not\kern -.6em \implies U<V, V<W.$

For any of the probabilities of an inequality involving just two variables,
for example $P(U<V),$ you might first consider the probability $P(U=V)$;
and then in the case $U\neq V,$ consider which variable is more likely to be greater, $U$ or $V$?
(This technique applies to discrete joint distributions too, not just continuous ones.)

There are various ways of computing $P(U<V,V<W).$ The most obvious is to consider the joint distribution of $(U,V,W)$ over the cube
$\{(u,v,w) \mid 0< u< 1, 0< v< 1, 0< w< 1\}.$
This is a uniform distribution, that is, the density function of $(U,V,W)$ on this cube is $f(u,v,w) = 1.$
So the probability of an event $A$ is simply
$$ P(A) = \int_A f(u,v,w) = \int_A 1.$$

For the event $A = \{U<V\} \cap \{V<W\}$ you can integrate
$$ \int_A 1 = \int_{U<V,V<W} 1 = \int_?^?\int_?^?\int_?^? 1 \, du\,dv\,dw,$$
provided that you replace each "?" with the correct formula so that you only integrate over $(u,v,w)$ where $u < v < w.$

Alternatively, you might notice that the event $U<V, V<W$ tells you that the three variables $U,$ $V,$ and $W$ occur in that exact sequence along the number line, that is, $U<V<W.$
Now ask what is the probability that $W$ is the largest of the three variables;
and given that $W$ is largest, which is more likely to be the next largest,
$U$ or $V$? What about the possibility that there is a tie for the largest variable or the second largest variable?
The answers to these questions let you compute $P(U<V, V<W).$

As another alternative, find the probability that there are any two variables amount $U,$ $V,$ and $W$ that are equal.
Then list all the possible cases where there are no two equal variables.
One such case is $U<V<W.$ What other cases are there, and which case is more likely than which other case?
This way of computing $P(U<V, V<W)$ may have the simplest arithmetic, but it requires seeing certain symmetries of the problem correctly.